# How can I prevent Kid Icarus from autosaving?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Kid Icarus: Uprising weapon fusion guides recommend testing out fusions to see if you can make something good and popping the cartridge (**before leaving the fusion menu**) if things don't work out, so the game doesn't save. Unfortunately, with an eShop copy of the game, there is no cartridge to pop. Most other actions that stop the game, such as closing it from the Home menu or pressing the power button, will trigger an autosave. Is there some easy way to prevent a save on an eShop copy of the game?

Comment: Well, you could still pull the plug or battery....

Comment: Sounds like it was designed very deliberately to attempt to disallow this.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it shows a preview of every combination when selected. So this is only for multi-step combinations, correct?

Comment: @Brian: Yup. It's hard to tell in advance what you can make from the results of your first-stage fusions.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed. I actually have a really expensive and roundabout way of handling that, but it also requires a physical cartridge. I enabled KI:U streetpass on my girlfriend's 3DS in addition to mine, so I can trade weapon gems to myself. I then combine the gems (that's the expensive part), so get to have the new weapon and still keep both old weapons.